# c# parallel arrays data from text file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text

Here's the problem: **Index was outside the bounds of the array.** Assignment: *Write a program that determines the number of students who can still enroll in a given class. Design your solution using parallel arrays. Test your solution by retrieving the following data from a text file. Define a exception class for this problem if the current enrollment exceeds the maximum enrollment by more than three. Halt the program and display a message indicating which course is over-enrolled.*

Here's the original code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        private static string[] classes = { "CS150", "CS250", "CS270", "CS300", "CS350" };

        private static int[] currentEnrolled = { 18, 11, 9, 4, 20 };

        private static int[] maxEnrollment = { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 };

        private static int currentEnrollment()
        {
            int enrolled = 0;
            foreach (int i in currentEnrolled)
            {
                enrolled += i;
            }
            return enrolled;
        }
        private static void listClasses()
        {
            foreach (string i in classes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class: {0}", i);
            }
        }

        private static void ClassStatus()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currentEnrolled.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class: {0}, Max: {1}, Current: {2}, remaining: {3}", classes[i], maxEnrollment[i], currentEnrolled[i], maxEnrollment[i] - currentEnrolled[i]);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Currently Enrolled: {0}", currentEnrollment());
            ClassStatus();
            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I've been editing the above code to take a text file instead, however I get an error. Here's what I'm working with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        private static string[] classes = new string[900];
        private static int[] currentEnrolled = new int[900];
        private static int[] maxEnrollment = new int[900];

        private static int currentEnrollment()
        {
            int enrolled = 0;
            foreach (int i in currentEnrolled)
            {
                enrolled += i;
            }
            return enrolled;
        }
        private static void listClasses()
        {
            foreach (string i in classes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class: {0}", i);
            }
        }

        private static void ClassStatus()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currentEnrolled.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class: {0}, Max: {1}, Current: {2}, remaining: {3}", classes[i], maxEnrollment[i], currentEnrolled[i], maxEnrollment[i] - currentEnrolled[i]);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("classes.txt");
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("classes.txt"))
            {

                string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                while (i < 900 && i < parts.Length)
                {
                        classes[i] = parts[1];
                    currentEnrolled[i] = int.Parse(parts[2]);
                    maxEnrollment[i] = int.Parse(parts[3]);
                }
                    i++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Currently Enrolled: {0}", currentEnrollment());
            ClassStatus();
            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the components used in the above code were taken from this article: [Splitting data from a text file into parallel arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860633/splitting-data-from-a-text-file-into-parallel-arrays)

Text file looks like this:

```
CS150,18,20
CS250,11,20
CS270,32,25
CS300,4,20
CS350,20,20
```

Any assistance will be appreciated. And yes, this is an assignment. Programming is most definitely not my strong suit.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: Yes. The debugger would stop and output the above error at the following line: `maxEnrollment[i] = int.Parse(parts[3]);` @DanielMann

Comment: Arrays in .NET are zero based: `parts[0] parts[1] parts[2]`, also your  `while` loop is wrong. Check the index `i`!

Comment: I removed the "parallel processing" tag. Having multiple arrays does not make your code parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be multiple problems with your while loop.

First, `parts.Length` will always be 3, since you have 2 commas and split on that. So the condition `i < 900 && i < parts.Length` does not really make sense, it's like `i < 900 and i < 3`, so it will always stop at 3. The intent is not really clear here, I think you meant to loop on each 900 values, but fi so`foreach` already does that for you.

Next, since there's 3 parts and C# arrays are 0-based, it should be `parts[0]`, `parts[1]` and `parts[2]`. That's what causing your 'out of range' exception.

Finally, `i++;` should be in your `while` loop. If you leave it outside, you will loop forever as the index will never increase.

Basically, it should be something like this :

```
            while (i < 900)
            {
                classes[i] = parts[0];
                currentEnrolled[i] = int.Parse(parts[1]);
                maxEnrollment[i] = int.Parse(parts[2]);
                i++;
            }
```

Again, the 900 is not really clear since you don't have 900 values per line (remember you're in a `foreach`). In my opinion you might as well scratch all that and redo it carefully.

What you need to do, is the following :

```
Read the file and store all the lines
Foreach line do:
    Split the line in 3 parts
    Store each separate part
Write results
```

For the "custom exception" part, you can add:

```
For the length of currentEnrollment do:
    If currentEnrollment at current index is superior than maxEnrollment at current index do:
        Throw a new exception with the className at current index
```

Comment: I made the following changes. I also changed 900 to 9. However, when I run the program, it basically outputs the first line of the text file 9 times.

Comment: Yeah, because you're looping on the same line. The foreach gives you each line separately, then you loop again with each parts. I'll add some pseudocode to help.